# Understanding Parallel.For Loop and local variables

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I am new in the parallel computing and I'm with some problems running a `Parallel.For` in C#.
I'm trying visit multiple Web Sites in simultaneous, get the HTML and register them in multiple SQLite Database.
Everything seems work fine until I check the results more precisely.
I noticed that in one loop for 0 to 20, the code entered 20 times in the shared part of loop and only 16 times in local part. So, was missing 4 results.
To understand the problem I made a experience where I only put two counters. One in the global part and another in the local. The output of global count was 20 and in the local part 1! After that I put a 2 seconds sleep before the returning of global part to the local part. In this case the output of global count was 20 and in the local part was 13! Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
static void ParalellCalc()
{
    var tm = new Stopwatch();
    tm.Start();
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    var parl = Parallel.For<int>(0, 20,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount},
        () => 0, (i, state, Enrada) =>
    {
        count++;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return Enrada;
    },
    (x) =>
    {
        count2++;
    });

    tm.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(tm.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Global: " + count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Local: " + count2.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(tm.Elapsed);
    tm.Reset();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I go into your suggestions and I made the same example with the `Interlocked.Increment` to increment the counters. The produced results are exactly the same. If I remove the `Thread.Sleep(2000)` the second counter produce the result of 1!? If I don't remove produce the result of 16. The first counter display in all the cases the value of 20 as should be. Anyone can explain that?

```
static void ParalellCalc()
{
    var tm = new Stopwatch();
    tm.Start();
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    var parl = Parallel.For<int>(0, 20,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount},
        () => 0, (i, state, Enrada) =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        return Enrada;
    },
    (x) =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count2);
    });

    tm.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(tm.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Global: " + count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Local: " + count2.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(tm.Elapsed);
    tm.Reset();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in parallel and not asynchronously? Downloading data is an I/O bound operation and is unlikely to benefit very much from parallelism.

Comment: Parrellel doesnt manage the threads, so each sleep might be 2 seconds but could also be longer depending on how the pool manages it. Basically it creates a thread then it then hands it off to a pool to manage when work gets done. Just because you made one thread first doesnt mean the manager will start working on that thread first or even next.

Comment: The `Parallel` class is the wrong tool for initiating I/O operations. Use this class when you have work for *your* CPU to do, not for the CPU of remote web servers. The right tool for the job is the [TPL Dataflow Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). This library offers a full set of options, can handle both CPU-bound and I/O-bound operations, and will allow you to control the concurrency level precisely.

Comment: @DanielMann i never thinked in the asynchronous way. What do you suggest? Get the HTML's asynchronously and trigger an event that saves the data in the databases when url is downloaded?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the problem here is not the management of I/O process. I think that my problem is not that. I have no problems writing the data. My problem is that the every thread is not returning to the local function.  made this example that proves that not all threads go through the local part of the loop. Can you explain me why without the Thread.Sleep(2000) the loop only enters on time in the local part?
Best regards.

Comment: 2023 update: the correct tool for parallelizing asynchronous I/O operations is now the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API, available in .NET 6 and later. I no longer recommend the TPL Dataflow for this purpose.

Comment: Related question: [How to prevent Parallel.ForEach loop from changing the number of tasks during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698775/how-to-prevent-parallel-foreach-loop-from-changing-the-number-of-tasks-during-ru)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Parallel.For` method parallelizes the workload by splitting it into partitions. The number of partitions and the size of each partition is determined by internal heuristics. Your experiment demonstrates that a workload of 20 items can be split in only 1 partition, or in 16 partitions, depending in the duration of the processing of each item. By adding the line `Thread.Sleep(2000)` you are changing your workload from extremely light to quite heavy, and so more partitions are created to balance the workload. These 16 partitions are typically processed by fewer than 16 threads, because each thread processes more than one partitions.

For a better understanding of how `Parallel.For` works you should log more info than the two counters `count` and `count2`. You should also have one counter for each thread, using a [`ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) with keys the [ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid) of each thread.

Comment: Good explanation Theodor, i think that i understand now. Do you suggest some technique to secure that every thread will be treated individually in the local part of the loop?

Comment: @MarcoTeixeira yes. You can create and use your own [`Partitioner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner-1) or, if you want absolute control, don't use `Parallel.For`! You can start threads manually, or use thread-pool threads with `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 4):

`++` operator is not thread safe, because it's not atomic. [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8) is thread safe. `Interlocked.Increment(ref count)` instead of `count++` and the same for `count2` would probably fix the counting.

Comment: Yes, you right. The loop is not thread safe, and i now that. But my question is. Independent of the code is thread safe or not, in the final of the process i should not have the count = 20 and the count2 = 20? The loop should not enter in the local part one time per thread?

Answer (score 2):

Parallel.For executes the Action you pass in in parallel (not guaranteed, but in this case most likely true). So the first thing to note is that you have a race-condition inside your parallel.for by potentially accessing and writing to counter from multiple threads. By sourrounding the `counter++` part of your code with a locking mechanism (such as `lock(obj)`) you should be able to solve the race condition.

Comment: You are better off using @Renat's `Interlocked` solution than using a lock around a `counter++` statement.

Comment: @Flydog57 while true, I think OP was using his posted code as an example (he mentioned SQL-Databases as his actual use case). Therefor I think providing the more general approach of locks is more useful in this case.

Comment: But i don't understand @EikeS. Every thread should not enter in the local part? And when the loop enters in the local part the data that i return from global part is not locked in this context?