# C# How Parallel.ForEach / Parallel.For partitioning works

Tags: c#, partitioning, parallel.foreach

I have some basic questions about **Parallel.ForEach with partition approach** and I'm facing some problems with them so I'd like to understand how this code works and what is the flow of it.

### Code sample

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 5), () => new StringBuilder(), (x, option, sb) =>
{
    sb.Append(x);
    return sb;
}, sb =>
{
    lock (result)
    {
        result.Append(sb.ToString());
    }
});
```

---

**Questions related to the code above:**

1. Are they doing some **partition work** inside parallel foreach ?
2. When I debug the code, I can see that the iteration (execution) of the code happens more then 5 times, but as I understand it is supposed to fire only 5 times - `Enumerable.Range(1, 5)` .
3. When will be this code fired ? In both `Parallel.Foreach` and `Parallel.For` there are two blocks separated by `{}`. How these two blocks are executing and interact with each other?

```
    lock (result)
    {
       result.Append(sb.ToString());
    }
```

---

Bonus Q:

See this this block of code where 5 iteration not occurring rather more iteration is taking place. when i use Parallel For instead of **foreach**. see the code and tell me where i made the mistake.

```
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    Parallel.For(1, 5, () => new StringBuilder(), (x, option, sb) =>
    {
        sb.Append("line " + x + System.Environment.NewLine);
        MessageBox.Show("aaa"+x.ToString());
        return sb;
        
    }, sb =>
    {
        lock (result)
        {
            result.Append(sb.ToString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217808/discussion-on-question-by-indi-rain-c-how-parallel-foreach-parallel-for-parti).

Comment: Related: [How to prevent Parallel.ForEach loop from changing the number of tasks during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698775/how-to-prevent-parallel-foreach-loop-from-changing-the-number-of-tasks-during-ru)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several misunderstands regarding how `Parallel.XYZ` works.

Couple of great points and suggestions have been mentioned in the comments, so I won't repeat them. Rather I would like to share some thoughts about Parallel programming.

#### The Parallel Class

Whenever we are talking about parallel programming we are usually distinguishing two kinds: **Data parallelism** and **Task parallelism**. The former is executing the same function(s) over a chunk of data in parallel. The latter is executing several independent functions in parallel.

(There is also a 3rd model called pipeline which is kind a mixture of these two. I won't spend time on it if you are interested about that one I would suggest to search for [Task Parallel Library's Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) or [System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).)

The Parallel class supports both of the models. The `For` and `ForEach` are designed for data parallelism, while the `Invoke` for task parallelism.

#### Partitioning

In case data parallelism the tricky part is how do you slice your data to get the best throughput / performance. You have to put into the account the size of the data collection, the structure of the data, the processing logic and the available cores (and many more other aspects as well). So there is no one-rule-for-all suggestion.

The main concern about partitioning is to not under-use the resources (some cores are idle, while others are working hard) and neither over-use (there are way more waiting jobs than available cores, so the synchronization overhead can be significant).

Let's suppose your processing logic is firmly stable (in other words various input data will not change significantly the processing time). In this case you can load balance the data between the executors. If an executor finishes then it can grab the new piece of data to be processed.

The way how you choose which data should go to which executor can be defined by the `Partitioner`([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl)). By default .NET support Range, Chunk, Hash and Striped partitioning. Some are static (the partitioning is done before any processing) and some of them are dynamic (depending on the processing speed some executor might receive more than other ones).

The following two excellent articles can give you better insight how each of the partitioning works:

- [Dixin's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/parallel-linq-2-partitioning)
- [Nima's blog](https://www.nimaara.com/practical-parallelization-with-map-reduce-in-c/)

#### Thread Safety

If each of the executor can execute its processing task without the need to interact with others than they are considered independent. If you can design your algorithm to have independent processing units then you minimize the synchronization.

In case of `For` and `ForEach` each partition can have its own partition-local-storage. That means the computations are independent because the intermediate results are stored in a partition aware storage. But as usual you want to merge these into a single collection or even into value.

That's the reason why these `Parallel` methods have `body` and `localFinally` [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For__1_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Func___0__System_Func_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState___0___0__System_Action___0__). The former is used to define the individual processing, while the latter is the aggregate and merge function. (It is kinda similar to the Map-Reduce approach) In the latter you have aware of [thread safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop-with-thread-local-variables) by yourself.

#### PLINQ

I don't want to explore this topic, which outside of the scope of the question. But I would like to give you a notch where to get started:

- [MS Whitepaper about when to use Parallel and when to use PLINQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf)
- [Common pitfalls of PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq)

#### Useful resources

- [Joe Albahari's Parallel Programming](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx)
- [BlackWasp's Parallel Programming](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ParallelTutorial.aspx)

---

EDIT: How to decide that it's worth to run in parallel?

There is no single formula (at least to my knowledge) which will tell you when does it make sense to use parallel execution. As I tried to highlight in the Partitioning section is a quite complex topic, so several experiments and fine-tuning are needed to find the optimal solution.

I highly encourage you to measure and try several different settings.

Here is my guideline how you should tackle this:

1. Try to understand the current characteristics of your application
2. Perform several different measurements to spot the execution bottleneck
3. Capture the current solution's performance metrics as your baseline
4. If it possible try to extract that piece of code from the code base to ease the fine-tuning
5. Try to tackle the same problem with several different aspects and with various inputs
6. Measure them and compare them to your baseline
7. If you are satisfied with the result then put that piece of code into your code base and measure again under different workloads
8. Try to capture as many relevant metrics as you can
9. If it is possible consider to execute both (sequential and parallel) solutions and compare their results.
10. If you are satisfied then get rid of the sequential code

#### Details

1. There several really good tools that can help you to get insight about your application. For .NET Profiling I would encourage you to give it try to [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/). [Concurrency Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConcurrencyVisualizer2019) is also good tool if no need custom metrics.
2. By several measurements I meant that you should measure several times with several different tools to exclude special circumstances. If you measure only once then you can get false positive result. So, measure twice, cut once.
3. Your sequential processing should serve as a baseline. Base over-parallelization can cause certain overhead that's why it make sense to be able to compare your new shine solution with current one. Under utilization can also cause significant performance degradation.
4. If you can extract your problematic code than you can perform micro-benchmarks. I encourage you to take a look at the awesome [Benckmark.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) tool to create benchmarks.
5. The same problem can be solved many in ways. So try to find several different approaches (like **Parallel**, **PLINQ** can be used more or less for the same problems)
6. As I said earlier measure, measure and measure. You should also keep in mind .NET try to be smart. What I mean by that for example `AsParallel` [does not give you a guarantee that it will run in parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#do-not-assume-that-iterations-of-foreach-for-and-forall-always-execute-in-parallel). .NET analysis your solution and data structure and decide how to run it. On the other hand you can [enforce parallel execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-execution-mode-in-plinq) if you are certain that it will help.

9. There are libraries like [Scientist.NET](https://github.com/scientistproject/Scientist.net) which can help you to perform this short of parallel run and compare process.

11. Enjoy :D

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have only one question for how much data we should go for parallel ? say for example i have a common routine where i pass a List<T> and list may have small data and some time list may have huge data. parallel works fine for large data handling but this also slow down the execution when there is small data. so i need to know for how much data i should go for Parallel? it would be nice you explain it in details with example. thanks

Comment: @Indi_Rain I've extend my response, please check it.